# OSQA: lost access to web-site due to changing allowed IP (admin's maintenance-mode)

Tags: osqa

I am the admin of a OSQA system (which is cool and great, by the way).

I tried to learn and understand the "maintenance mode", in order to create backups. So I have entered the "maintenance mode", and there I saw the text box with the message that my users will see when the site is under maintenance mode. Plus, there was a list of IPs that will be allowed to access the site even if it is under maintenance mode.

My IP was there...

My mistake was that **I changed the IP in that text box**, in order to see what my users will see. Immediately, I lost access the web site, and all I can see is the message, as the rest of my users... (at least now I know that it works - users cannot access the site, and they DO see the message...)

How can I regain access to my web site?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have acces to the server where your site is hosted?
if so you just need to enter in django shell: *python manage.py shell*
then run the following code:

```
from forum import settings
  settings.MAINTAINANCE_MODE.set_value(None)
  exit()
```

With that the maintainance mode will be disable and you will be able to modify the allowed IP's.

~Mike

Comment: +1 for the response! I will try that. in the meantime, i "cheated" by changing the IP of the machine where OSQA was installed, and I set it to the "allowed" IP, so I was able to enter as admin and disable the maintenance mode. Thanks! (BTW I've posted this same Q in meta.osqa.com, but this Q&A seems to be inactive.